# How to remove dot after month in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, macros

I would like to use custom labels for bibliography in the form "Month Year". For that, I use custom bib environment with label printed by:

```
\printfield{month}%
\printfield{year}
```

However, it gives me strings like "Oct. 2019" while I'd prefer "Oct 2019".

Question: How to remove the dot from month's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates should be printed via the dedicated date commands like `\printdate` and friends, not with `\printfield{month}\printfield{year}`.

In any case the dot is hard-coded into the month bibstrings, so to get rid of it you need to redefine the bibstrings. For example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  january          = {Jan},
  february         = {Feb},
  march            = {Mar},
  april            = {Apr},
  may              = {May},
  june             = {June},
  july             = {July},
  august           = {Aug},
  september        = {Sept},
  october          = {Oct},
  november         = {Nov},
  december         = {Dec},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ctan,baez/online,markey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Baez, John C. and Aaron D. Lauda (27th Oct 2004). Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups. Version 3. arXiv: math/0307200v3.//CTAN (2006). CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. url: http://www.ctan.org (visited on 01/10/2006).//Markey, Nicolas (16th Oct 2005). Tame the BeaST. The B to X of BibTeX. Version 1.3. url: http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf (visited on 01/10/2006).]

Comment: Thank you! I've accepted your answer.